# Change color to label

Tags: jquery, colors, label

I have a label, dinamically created

```
<label onclick="amplicon_click(this)" id="AMPL1324730364" >AMPL1324730364</label>
```

In the document ready function i call the changeColor function to change the color, but it doesn't work. I also tried to change it with jquery and css and it doesn't work either. What's wrong here?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                var circos_amplicon = "<?php echo $circos_amplicon; ?>";
            amplicon_click(circos_amplicon);
                            changeColor("AMPL1324730364",'orange');
                            $("#AMPL1324730364").css("color", "orange");

    }); 

    function changeColor(id, newColor) {
        $("#" + id).css("color", newColor);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Where is your label created?, maybe at the time you call changeColor() the element is not there, check in changeColor if your $("#"+id) is returning you an element.

Comment: i add a alert to changeColor,and it's fine.. it says #AMPL1324730364. But color doesn't change at all

Comment: But the $("#"+id) is returning you the element?

Comment: function changeColor(id, newColor) {
alert("#" + id);
$("#" + id).css("color", newColor);
}

Comment: Do something like console.log($("#"+id).length) to check if an element is selected.

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/2qRk4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do it with css. Add a class to that label

```
<label class="lbl" onclick="amplicon_click(this)" id="AMPL1324730364" >AMPL1324730364</label>
```

Then, in css,

```
.lbl{ color:red }
```

or you can do it with jquery also

**jquery**

```
$(".lbl").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: I try to do this with jquery and css, in the document.ready function but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies elsewhere. This code works just fine:

```
<label  id="AMPL1324730364">AMPL1324730364</label>
```

And the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    changeColor("AMPL1324730364", 'orange');
});

function changeColor(id, newColor) {
    $("#" + id).css("color", newColor);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9fe9/)**

Is this label being created after the page load?

Comment: yes is create after... but is created with the function             amplicon_click(circos_amplicon);
that is before the changeColor call

Comment: Then you need to call the function to change it's color **after** it is added to the page. There may be some delay in it's creation, can you add a callback to `amplicon_click(circos_amplicon);`?